# Add up two array variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have $product['price'] and $option['price'] and I want to add these two together and echo the result. These are in two separate arrays eg $product = array { price => 1 } and $option = array { price => 1 }

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one option, like you mentioned:

```
$total = $product['price'] + $option['price'];
echo $total;
```

For multiple options, assuming you have an array of $options:

```
$total = $product['price'];
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $total = $total + $option['price'];
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an actual answer and not just throwing abuse :)

Comment: No problem. ;)  If you can, accept it as the answer so we can end the abuse haha.

Comment: Will do when it lets me. Is there a way of adding every $option['price'] if there's say 3 for example? So if there was 2 options you're adding to the product, warranty and delivery both of these are represented by the $option['price'] variable but with the code above it only adds the last option price to the figure

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of using a foreach loop to do multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = $product['price'] + $option['price'];
```

if there are many prices, like $option['price'][0], $option['price'][1] and so on, then to add all the prices, we can do the following:

```
$sum = $product['price'];
foreach ($option['price'] as $key => $value) {
    $sum = $sum + $value;
}

echo $sum;
```